# Download de Drivers USB para Motorola

Tags: android, eclipse

Quero testar meus apps Android diretamente no meu Moto G, mas não estou conseguindo conectar ele ao Eclipse, pois está faltando o driver USB.

E o link de download no Android Developers (http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/USB_Drivers/) direciona para outra página.

E também não achei no site da Motorola.

Alguém já conseguiu baixar?

Comment: A pergunta é válida, mas você errou de site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usei esse [link da Motorola](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/97326/p/30,6720,9050) pra baixar o driver e rodar usando o [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), mas é provável que funcione pro `Eclipse` também.

Comment: vlw!! vou tentar aki

Comment: Estranho, tenho um Moto X e não precisei fazer nada disso. Configurou o modo desenvolvedor e ativou o debug no aparelho?

Comment: Em sistemas `MacOSX` não precisa fazer nada, geralmente no `Windows` que precisamos instalar esse driver